# Strange blocks appeared in my program

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, programming

[image]

In my Mindstorms program, I found these strange blocks. They appeared when I sent this program to my other PC on Windows 10, which is more powerful. They don't work and I can't change them. Mindstorms just stopped working on old PC on Windows 10   and it crashes every time I try to open any program. Now I even can't delete them! Help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lego Mindstorms Ev3 home edition on Mac OS Mojave bug - bricks sometimes go blank](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/10412/lego-mindstorms-ev3-home-edition-on-mac-os-mojave-bug-bricks-sometimes-go-blan)